# How to replace the legacy function "doQueries " to AMD ESRI Javascript format?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers, migration

I'm trying to understand the migration of ESRI API for javascript, from legacy to AMD. In the case of this example, how replace the  fucntion doqueries????:

```
function init() {
    map = new esri.Map("map", {
      extent: new esri.geometry.Extent(-102.61, 36.2, -93.82, 40.5, new esri.SpatialReference({wkid: 4326})),
      slider: false
    });
    dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", doQueries);
    map.addLayer(new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D/MapServer"));
  }

  function doQueries(map) {
    //Query all counties in Kansas
    var countyQueryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3");
    var countyQuery = new esri.tasks.Query();
    countyQuery.outFields = ["*"];
    countyQuery.returnGeometry = true;
    countyQuery.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
    countyQuery.where = "STATE_NAME = 'Kansas'";
    countyQueryTask.execute(countyQuery, addCountyFeatureSetToMap);

    //Query all cities in Kansas
    var cityQueryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer/0/");
    var cityQuery = new esri.tasks.Query();
    cityQuery.outFields = ["*"];
    cityQuery.returnGeometry = true;
    cityQuery.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
    cityQuery.where = "STATE_NAME = 'Kansas'";
    cityQueryTask.execute(cityQuery, addCityFeatureSetToMap);
  }

  function addCountyFeatureSetToMap(featureSet) {
    var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol();
    symbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([150,150,150,0.5]));

    //Create graphics layer for counties
    var countyLayer = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();
    map.addLayer(countyLayer);

    var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate("${NAME}","${*}");

    //Add counties to the graphics layer
    dojo.forEach(featureSet.features, function(feature) {
      countyLayer.add(feature.setSymbol(symbol).setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate));
    });
  }

  function addCityFeatureSetToMap(featureSet) {
    var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol();
    symbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([0,0,255]));

    //Create graphics layer for cities
    var cityLayer = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();
    map.addLayer(cityLayer);
    map.reorderLayer(cityLayer,1);

    var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate("${CITY_NAME}","${*}");

    //Add cities to the graphics layer
    dojo.forEach(featureSet.features, function(feature) {
      cityLayer.add(feature.setSymbol(symbol).setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate));
    });
  }

  dojo.addOnLoad(init);
```

Answer (score 3):

I've converted this to AMD below. Specific things to point out:

- use require() to load modules instead of dojo.require()
- no longer use any esri.whatever globals
- no longer use any dojo.whatever globals
- dojo/domReady (or dojo/ready) replaces dojo.addOnLoad or dojo.ready
- use object.on to listen to events, this replaces dojo.connect (example is map.on(), this is  not specific to AMD)
- take a look at this AMD require generator until you get a handle on module names and recommended aliases:  http://swingley.github.io/arg/

Code using AMD rather than legacy globals stuff:

```
var map;

require([
    "esri/map", "esri/geometry/Extent", "esri/SpatialReference",
    "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
    "esri/tasks/query", "esri/tasks/QueryTask", 
    "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
    "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
    "dojo/_base/Color", "dojo/_base/array",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(
    Map, Extent, SpatialReference, 
    ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer,
    Query, QueryTask,
    SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleMarkerSymbol, 
    InfoTemplate, GraphicsLayer,
    Color, arrayUtils
) {
    map = new Map("map", {
      extent: new Extent(-102.61, 36.2, -93.82, 40.5, new SpatialReference({wkid: 4326})),
      slider: false
    });
    map.on("load", doQueries);
    map.addLayer(new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D/MapServer"));

  function doQueries(map) {
    //Query all counties in Kansas
    var countyQueryTask = new QueryTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3");
    var countyQuery = new Query();
    countyQuery.outFields = ["*"];
    countyQuery.returnGeometry = true;
    countyQuery.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
    countyQuery.where = "STATE_NAME = 'Kansas'";
    countyQueryTask.execute(countyQuery, addCountyFeatureSetToMap);

    //Query all cities in Kansas
    var cityQueryTask = new QueryTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer/0/");
    var cityQuery = new Query();
    cityQuery.outFields = ["*"];
    cityQuery.returnGeometry = true;
    cityQuery.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
    cityQuery.where = "STATE_NAME = 'Kansas'";
    cityQueryTask.execute(cityQuery, addCityFeatureSetToMap);
  }

  function addCountyFeatureSetToMap(featureSet) {
    var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol();
    symbol.setColor(new Color([150,150,150,0.5]));

    //Create graphics layer for counties
    var countyLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
    map.addLayer(countyLayer);

    var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${NAME}","${*}");

    //Add counties to the graphics layer
    arrayUtils.forEach(featureSet.features, function(feature) {
      countyLayer.add(feature.setSymbol(symbol).setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate));
    });
  }

  function addCityFeatureSetToMap(featureSet) {
    var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
    symbol.setColor(new Color([0,0,255]));

    //Create graphics layer for cities
    var cityLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
    map.addLayer(cityLayer);
    map.reorderLayer(cityLayer,1);

    var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${CITY_NAME}","${*}");

    //Add cities to the graphics layer
    arrayUtils.forEach(featureSet.features, function(feature) {
      cityLayer.add(feature.setSymbol(symbol).setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate));
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but when I run the script I have this error message:                                     ("NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://js.arcgis.com/3.7/js/esri/tasks/Query.js") the line of the error corresponds to this link: <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.7/"></script>

Comment: @Wika are you running the code I posted? My code using "esri/tasks/query" is not a typo– the module name for the Query class uses a lower-case "q" so make sure your require() dependency list uses "esri/tasks/query".

Comment: clearly,that was a syntax problem. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Wika glad I could help